# ienumerable to ienumerable<t> without losses

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method with accepts only `ienumerable<t>` parameters but my local value is a simple ienumerable.

I cannot change those conditions.

Now my question is how to get ienumerable to `ienumerable<t>` without losing the object reference of the items? I do not want to copy data or whatever.

Would the `ienumerable.Cast<object>()` do the job? I do not want new references of items I just want a `ienumerable<t>` from ienumerable as fast as possible.

Comment: Yes, `Cast<T>` is what you want.

Comment: But it does involve copying data. and producing new references. As all solutions will. Not a problem.

Comment: @HenkHolterman AFAIK it involves copying of the collection, but if the data is represented by reference type, objects will not be copied.

Comment: @HenkHolterman:  only value types have to be unboxed.

Comment: Yes or no? Does it create new reference of objects/structs?

Comment: @devhedgehog: no new objects if it's a reference type, otherwise it has to be unboxed which creates a new value. But that would happen also if you cast `object` to `int`.

Comment: A new reference is the same (cost) as a new `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two linq methods for this purpose: `Enumerable.Cast<T>`, which will throw an exception if any item from your source cannot be cast into `T`, or `Enumerable.OfType<T>`, which will skip elements that cannot be cast to `T` without throwing, but is a bit slower because it checks every element's type (`Enumerable.Cast<T>` just casts it to `T`).

Answer (score 6):

A Linq-Statement simply is a set of rules that get executed when someone requests items from the IEnumerable that the linq statement produces. A foreach is one such consumer, but any other consumer of IEnumerable will kick off the same rules before getting items, so you can always imagine working with a foreach as an analogy.

```
foreach(object item in myEnumerable)
{
    ((MyClass)item).DoSomething();
}
```

is conceptually the same as:

```
foreach(MyClass item in myEnumerable.Cast<MyClass>())
{
    item.DoSomething();
}
```

So no, there is no copying. But it should throw an error if you try to cast an item of the wrong type. If you want something more of the lines of this:

```
foreach(object item in myEnumerable)
{
    MyClass myItem = item as MyClass;
    if(myItem != null)
        myItem.DoSomething();
}
```

then you would use OfType():

```
foreach(MyClass item in myEnumerable.OfType<MyClass>())
{
    item.DoSomething();
}
```

Note that if you call ToList or ToArray on your enumerable, it will get evaluated by yourself (same stuff happens as if you'd call foreach), and it will be saved to a new collection. If your original IEnumerable contained value types (like int, float, structs, etc.) instead of reference types (like any of your own classes), then you will actually do have copies of the items in the new array. So only use those methods if you actually want to evaluate the linq query early.

Comment: The foreach can cast directly: `foreach(MyClass item in myEnumerable)`

Comment: I know, but for demonstration purposes I did the cast explicitly in body.

Comment: Idk what you mean here... I am not using foreach. I am using Parallel.ForEach(IEnumerable<T>..)

Comment: My bad, guess I confused it because they're also immutable, but it does make sense.

Comment: dev hedgehog: If you want to understand how IEnumerable works I recommend you check out examples for the yield return statement. This article explains it well: http://www.alteridem.net/2007/08/22/the-yield-statement-in-c/ For the IEnumerable it doesn't matter how it is evaluated, hence why I showed examples with foreach.

Comment: Or this one to see that IEnumerables do not even need to be finite, you can request items in a stream as long as you want them: http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.de/2011/07/c-yield-keyword-ienumerable-and.html

Answer (score 1):

As a complementary answer, in addition to `Cast<T>` and `OfType<T>` Extension methods, you can implement it manually (more useful for older frameworks or embedded ones like unity3d)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    public class WrapperEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable _enumerable;

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new WrapperEnumerator<T>(_enumerable.GetEnumerator());
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _enumerable.GetEnumerator();
        }

        public WrapperEnumerable(IEnumerable enumerable)
        {
            _enumerable = enumerable;
        } 
    }

    public class WrapperEnumerator<T>:IEnumerator<T>
    {
        private readonly IEnumerator _enumerator;

        public T Current
        {
            get { return (T)Convert.ChangeType(_enumerator.Current,typeof(T)); }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {           
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return _enumerator.Current; }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            return _enumerator.MoveNext();
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            _enumerator.Reset();
        }

        public WrapperEnumerator(IEnumerator enumerator)
        {
            _enumerator = enumerator;
        }
    }
}
```

and the usage would be like

```
    var list = new ArrayList {1, 2, 3};

    foreach(var n in new WrapperEnumerable<int>(list))
        Console.WriteLine(n);

    //using Cast method extension
    foreach (var n in list.Cast<int>())
        Console.WriteLine(n);

    //using OfType method extension
    foreach(var n in list.OfType<int>())
        Console.WriteLine(n);
```